# elasticsearch using NEST: document versioning

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, versioning, nest

I am using the Search function in NEST to search documents based on a searching criteria. I get back result.DocumentsWithMetaData that displays a list of documents that has Version property null. Am I supposed to do something more in order to get the version back from ES?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the integration test for it here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Search/VersionTests.cs

You will have to call `.Version()` if you want version information to be returned.

```
var queryResults = ElasticClient.Search<MyDoc>(s => s
    .Version()
);
```